# Creating a Doubly Linked List from extending from a Singly Linked List - getting Null Pointer

Tags: java, list, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I have been trying to utilize my previous made singly linked list to create a doubly linked list. So, in the Node class I added a previous node reference and updated the `add` and `insert` methods in the `List` class to accommodate going back and forth within the `DoublyLinked` list class. `add` puts the new node after the current node and `insert` puts the new node before the current node in the `List` class; this is because I want to add and insert my values in ascending order within the `DoublyLinked` list class. [This may sound confusing but I will post the code below] When I test my `add` method [in the `DoublyLinked` class] I get a null pointer exception.

As I said I have been working on this for a few days, so in that time I have taken in consideration these previous questions:

1. [How do I change a singly-linked list to a doubly-linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771808/how-do-i-change-a-singly-linked-list-to-a-doubly-linked-list)
2. [Singly linked list to doubly linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208579/singly-linked-list-to-doubly-linked-list)
3. [Null pointer when using doubly linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224445/null-pointer-when-using-doubly-linked-list)

**List.java**

```
public class List<T> implements ListInterface<T> {
        protected class Node {
        private T value = null;
        private Node prev = null;
        private Node next = null;

        public T getValue( ) {
            return value;
        }

        public Node getPrev( ) {
            return prev;
        }

        public Node getNext( ) {
            return next;
        }

        public void setValue( T newValue ) {
            value = newValue;
        }

        public void setPrev( Node prevNode ) {
            prev = prevNode;
        }

        public void setNext( Node nextNode ) {
            next = nextNode;
        }
    }

    protected Node head = null;
    protected Node cur  = null;
    protected int      size = 0;

    // add after cur
    @Override
    public void add( T value ) {
        Node temp = new Node( );
        temp.setValue( value );
        size++ ;
        if (isEmpty( )) {
            head = temp;
            cur = temp;
        } else {
            temp.setNext(cur.getNext());
            temp.setPrev(cur);
            cur.setNext(temp);
            cur = temp;
        }
    }

    // insert before cur
    @Override
    public void insert( T value ) {
        Node temp = new Node( );
        temp.setValue( value );
        size++ ;
        if (isEmpty( )) {
            head = temp;
            cur = temp;
        } else if (head == cur) {
            head = temp;
            head.setNext( cur );
            cur.setPrev(head);
            cur = head;
        } else {
            Node prev = head;
            while( prev.getNext( ) != cur ) {
                prev = prev.getNext( );
            }
            temp.setNext( prev.getNext( ) );
            temp.setPrev(prev);
            prev.setNext( temp );
            cur = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**DoublyLinked.java**

```
public class DoublyLinked<T extends Comparable<T>> 
extends List<T> implements ListInterface<T> {

    private int size;
    private Node tail;

    DoublyLinked() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T value) {
        size++;

        reset();
        // getting Null pointer on add when doublinked list is empty
        if(isEmpty()) {
            super.add(value);
            head = cur;
            tail = head;
            cur = head;
        }
        else {
            try {
                while(value.compareTo(get()) > 0 && hasNext()) { // error here
                    next();
                    if(value.compareTo(get()) <= 0) {
                        super.add(value);
                        // how to set cur to this new node?
                    }
                }
            } catch (EmptyListException | EndOfListException e) {}  
            super.add(value); // add at end of list
            tail = cur;
            cur = tail;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T get() throws EmptyListException {
        return cur.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() throws EmptyListException, EndOfListException {
        if (!hasNext( )) {
            throw new EndOfListException( );
        }
        cur = cur.getNext( );
        return cur.getValue( );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return((!isEmpty()) && (cur.getNext() != null));
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        cur = head;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size ==  0;
    }
}
```

Then I have a basic JUnit test to test the code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;


public class DoublyLinkedTest {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        DoublyLinked<Integer> list = new  DoublyLinked<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment `size` and then call `isEmpty()` (which checks whether `size` is zero) to decide how to add the item:

```
    size++ ;
    if (isEmpty( )) {
```